# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 1606: invalid start byte

Tags: python, file, txt

```
with open('stopwords.txt', 'r') as f:
    stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in f)
#spark off the consumer for the call of the record to system:
filename = input("enter filename to process: ")

word_counts = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # remove leading spaces and newline character
        line = line.lower() # convert to lower case 
        word = ''.join(c for c in word if c.isalpha() or c =="'"or c == "-")
        for word in line:
            if word not in stopwords:
                if word in word_counts:
                    word_counts[word] = word_counts[word] + 1 # increment count of word
            else:
                word_counts[word] = 1 # add word to   dictionary with count 1
for key in list(word_counts.keys()):
    print(key, ":", word_counts[key])
```

Here is the full error code:
enter filename to process: Greta_Thunberg_2019.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/alexahrnicek/Downloads/Extra Credit/PA_ExtraCredit.py", line 15, in 
for line in f:
File "", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 1606: invalid start byte

Comment: Try using f.readlines(), instead of just f in that comprehension

Comment: Your text file is either corrupt or not utf-8 encoded. What are the bytes starting at 0x97? You can try `with open(filename, 'r', errors="ignore") as f:` if you just want to ignore the errors, but you may be missing something from the file.

Comment: @PedroTurik Why would you use `f.readlines()`? he only thing you achieve with this is that you have overhead by unnecessarily creating a list.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay  I tried ignoring errors and the result came back with a different error saying 'word' is not defined so I am assuming it wasn't able to read the entire file. Is there a way to enable utf-8 coding? How do I know if the file is corrupt? The txt file contains words and also special characters such as '?' and '.' would that have something to do with the error?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edit your question with your updated code and full traceback (error message). Your code must attempt to read the `word` variable before it has been assigned to. It shouldn't have anything to do with the text file being read with errors ignored. Your code (by default) already attempts to decode the text file as being utf-8 encoded. The text file is either not utf-8 encoded, or it is corrupt. Where did the text file come from? How was it created? Link me to the text file and I'll take a look. The "special characters" shouldn't matter.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay file:///Users/alexahrnicek/Downloads/Extra%20Credit/Greta_Thunberg_2019.txt

Comment: That link won't work because it points to a file on your computer which only you can access. You'll need to upload the file to a file sharing website, then use the link it gives you. Try https://www.file.io/

Comment: @GordonAitchJay https://www.file.io/Xv8l/download/yh5B2aqEAcS2 sorry about that, thank you for your help!

Comment: For some reason I can't download the file. It said it was deleted for some reason. Try to upload it to https://fastupload.io/en

Comment: @GordonAitchJay https://fastupload.io/en/XoUwvyVOg8tg15u/file

Comment: Okay, so it turns out the text file is actually Windows-1252 encoded. Try: `with open(filename, 'r', encoding='mbcs') as f`. It might only work on Windows, though. If you want, just edit the text file and replace the hyphen on the 9th line, after: `acceptable to us — `. That's the character causing the problems. Replace it with `-`. If you do edit it, then you no longer need to specify the encoding in `open`.